# jquery onclick add background overlay for pullout

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am currently working on a simple pullout for a website based on a script I found somewhere on SO. Now I want to add a background overlay to the existing function, but I don't know how and where I have to call it.

Here is the fiddle of the pullout.

http://jsfiddle.net/hr9bymj1/

and this is the function

```
 $(function () {
   $("#clickme").click(function () {
        if ($(this).parent().hasClass("popped")) {
            $(this).parent().animate({
                left: '-400px'
            }, {
                queue: false,
                duration: 500
            }).removeClass("popped");

        } else {
            $(this).parent().animate({
                left: "0px"
            }, {
                queue: false,
                duration: 500
            }).addClass("popped");
        }
    });
});
```

I have tried some methods found in the internet, but I am not able to combine the click event corerectly with the append div and so I am stuck and trying to ask for help here.

Thank you!

Comment: Its unclear, What exactly you want?

Comment: you mean this http://jsfiddle.net/hr9bymj1/1/

Comment: or do you mean adding overlay class? like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hr9bymj1/3/)

Comment: I wish someone could help me how to add a background overlay div to this click function, like for the whole <body>, so that once the pullout is clicked/visible, it the rest of the site is covered with an overlay, light in lightbox, or other modal windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this.

Add another div with overlay class:

```
<div class="overlay">
</div>
<div id="slideout">
    <div id="slidecontent">
        I am the content. I am the king!
    </div>
    <div id="clickme">
    </div>
</div>
```

Update jQuery accordingly:

```
$(function () {

    $("#clickme").click(function () {
        if($(this).parent().hasClass("popped")){
            $(this).parent().animate({left:'-400px'}, {queue: false, duration: 500}).removeClass("popped");
            $(".overlay").fadeOut(500); //hide overlay on popin
        }else {
            $(this).parent().animate({left: "0px" }, {queue: false, duration: 500}).addClass("popped");
            $(".overlay").fadeIn(500); //show overlay on popout
        }
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hr9bymj1/8/)

Comment: yes, this looks really good, thank you. Is it possible to fade animate the show/hide function?

Comment: @Supapinzi Yeah!. You can use fade effect like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hr9bymj1/8/)

Comment: this is kinda perfect. thank you so much! actually pretty easy, as it looks, but i am new to Jquery  .

Comment: yeah you are right. thanks to the good people at stackoverflow I am learning a lot

Comment: do you have an idea how to close the pullout also by clicking on the .overlay class?

Comment: @Supapinzi As per quick solution, you can trigger click event of `#clickme` onClick of `.overlay` [see](http://jsfiddle.net/hr9bymj1/10/)

Comment: thank you my friend, this is perfect for what I was trying to do. very nice!

Answer (score 1):

You coul use a `:before` pseudo class on `#slideout`, so that it would cover up all the page and be visible only when the `#slideout` is `.popped`

Check out the **[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/xx2afs0n/2/)**

```js
$(function () {

    $("#clickme").click(function () {
        if($(this).parent().hasClass("popped")){
            $(this).parent().animate({left:'-400px'}, {queue: false, duration: 500}).removeClass("popped");
            
        }else {
            $(this).parent().animate({left: "0px" }, {queue: false, duration: 500}).addClass("popped");
        }
    });
});
```

```css
#slideout {
    background: #f4f4f4;
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    height: 150px;
    top: 30%;
    left:-400px;
    padding-left: 0;
}
/*the overlay bellow*/
#slideout:before{
    content: '';
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
#slideout.popped:before{
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

#clickme {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: -20px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background: tomato;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#slidecontent {
    float:left;
    padding: 35px;
}

.overlay {
    background-color: #000;
    bottom: 0;
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 50); /* IE7 & 8 */
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 49;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slideout">
    <div id="slidecontent">
        I am the content. I am the king!
    </div>
    <div id="clickme">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is also vera good, thank you. I really need to learn about pseudo classes. looks like they're pretty handy.

Comment: @Supapinzi no problem-o, glad to help out!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new class in the css with background image and the add the class to the body when it is clicked  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hr9bymj1/9/)

```js
$(function () {

    $("#clickme").click(function () {
        
        if($(this).parent().hasClass("popped")){
            $(this).parent().animate({left:'-400px'}, {queue: false, duration: 500}).removeClass("popped");
           $('body').removeClass("bg");
        
            
        }else {
            $(this).parent().animate({left: "0px" }, {queue: false, duration: 500}).addClass("popped");
           $('body').addClass('bg');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.bg{
 background:url('http://placekitten.com/300/301') ;
}

#slideout {
    background: #f4f4f4;
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    height: 150px;
    top: 30%;
    left:-400px;
    padding-left: 0;
    z-index: 50;
}
    
#clickme {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: -20px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background: tomato;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#slidecontent {
    float:left;
    padding: 35px;
}

.overlay {
    background-color: #000;
    bottom: 0;
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 50); /* IE7 & 8 */
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 49;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slideout">
    <div id="slidecontent">
        I am the content. I am the king!
    </div>
    <div id="clickme">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but I prefer to do it with a div instead of the body, like in the other example. thanks for the effort, though

Comment: @Supapinzi yeah  got it